# 5V to the discharge pin, threshold pin and trigger pin

Tags: integrated-circuit, timer, electronic-load, 555

What happens if I give 5V to the discharge pin, threshold pin and trigger pin of 555 without giving power at pin 8 and grounding at pin 1?

Answer (score 1):

If you only connect 5 volts to some pins on any IC, and make no connections to any other pin, nothing will happen, as there will be no voltage difference between different parts of the IC.